# No puedo hacer la transición de div y p

Tags: html, css

Buen día. 
Estoy intentando hacer una transición con el siguiente código, para que se muevan lento al momento de aparecer, pero no me funciona.
Mi código es el siguiente.

```
  <head>
      <style type="text/css">
   .circulo1{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue ;
  background-image: url("img/mision.jpg");
   background-size: 100% 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;


}
.circulo1:hover{
      transition: width 10s ease-in; 


}
 .mh{
  display: none;
}
.circulo1:hover + .mh{
  display: inline-block;

  transition: width 10s ease-in-out;
}
     </style>
 </head>
```

mi html es el siguiente

```
   <div class="col-sm-4 circulo1 "><h3 class="my-2"><br><br><br>
  <strong>Misi&oacute;n</strong></h3><p class="mh" >Hacer la 
   transici&oacute;n</p></div>
```

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar, no se en que me falla al momento de que se muevan.
Gracias

Comment: Sería mejor para ayudarte que subieras el html, pero a primera vista veo que no alteras en ningún momento el width, por lo que si no lo cambias no habrá transición

Comment: me podrías decir como lo puedo alterar, porque aun no se como

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas definiendo la animacion de la manera equivocado. Primero debes de definir la regla `transition` con la propiedad a animar, duración y tipo de transition y cuando se haga `:hover` sobre el elemento, la animacion tomara efecto.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:blue;
  transition: width 3s ease-in;
}

div:hover{
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Fijate como primero se define las reglas de la transition y luego al hacer `:hover` se aplica la animacion sobre las propiedades con la animación aplicada. En tu caso tenias definido la animación cuando se hacia `:hover` sobre elemento lo que era erróneo.

No se si esto es lo que quieres pero aquí tienes un ejemplo modificado de tu codigo con una animacion aplicada:

```css
.circulo1{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:blue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue ;
  background-image: url("img/mision.jpg");
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: width 10s ease-in;
}
.circulo1:hover{
  width:300px;
}
.mh{
  opacity:0;
  transition: opacity 10s ease-in;
  transition: width 10s ease-in;
  width:200px;
  background:yellow;
}
.circulo1:hover  .mh{
  opacity:1;
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
   <div class="col-sm-4 circulo1 "><h3 class="my-2"><br><br><br>
  <strong>Misi&oacute;n</strong></h3>
  <p class="mh" >Hacer la 
   transici&oacute;n</p></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, era lo que necesitaba